# R: Chi-squared comparing one reference group to two other groups

Tags: r, regression, chi-squared-test, descriptive-statistics, poisson-regression

If this question has been answered elsewhere, please direct me to the appropriate post. thank you!

Below is an example of part of my data. I am trying to determine if there is a statistically significant difference between the different groups of people regarding other variables, such as plan and region. I am only interested in the categorical data for the analysis but there are numerical variables as well that I have not shown below:

```
plan    region    group
HMO     NE        A
PPO     NE        A
HMO     S         B
Other   NE        B
POS     W         C
HMO     S         C
```

I would like to compare plans and regions of different groups of people using chi-square, where the reference is always A. As in, I would like to compare A to B and A to C. For example, I'd like to see if there is a difference between group A vs B and A vs C with regards to the number of people who live in the NE region.

I would like results like the following (please bear in mind my data actually has thousands of rows so n will not be 1):

```
               group A      group B      group C    p-value (A vs B)   p-value (A vs C)
plan (n, %)
    HMO        1, 50%       1, 50%       1, 50%       ?                 ?
    PPO        1, 50%       0, 0%        0, 0%        ?                 ?
    POS        0, 0%        0, 0%        1, 50%       ?                 ?
    Other      0, 0%        1, 50%       0, 0%        ?                 ?
```

and the same for region

I don't want to create two data frames to compare the counts separately.

Comment: This question would be best served on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is best done with poisson regression.  If you post your fill dataset, I can show you how.

Comment: @OTStats I originally posted this on Stack Overflow and was directed here.

Comment: This does not appear to be an R coding question to me. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Thank you. However, I do not want to use a regression because there is no real outcome here. I am interested in using descriptive statistics (hence chi-squared) to see if these groups differ in terms of their demographics (e.g., what region they live in and what insurance plan they are on). I considered ANOVA but that would end up comparing all three groups. My aim is to compare one group with the other two. Also, these variables are not necessarily count data.

Comment: @sh2 Ah, but that is where you are mistaken!  Regression can be a means of estimation as well as a means of description!  Poisson regression is essentially BUILT for estimating these kinds of things, and it can be shown that various diagnostics for poisson regression are exactly equivalent to the chisquare.  The only reason I suggest Poisson regression is because it allows for a natural way to set a reference group. Even if they are not count data, an appropriate regression would likely suffice.

Comment: @DemetriPananos That is interesting! Would you mind pointing me to a reference where I can read up on this? Would you also know of a research article in which a Poisson regression has been done as descriptive? Thank you.